# Access GridView Row Cell via Enum Extension a good idea?

Tags: c#, gridview, enums

Newbie here so not sure what are the potential performance issues here, and what are the best practices.

Is this a good idea?  Thoughts?

FROM THIS:
(prone to manual error when cells codes are all over the place and/or gridview changes)

```
row.Cells[1].Visible = false;   // CustomerId
row.Cells[9].Visible = false;   // OrderNumber
row.Cells[10].Visible = false;  // ProductId
. . .
int matchId = row.Cells[11].Text;
. . .
```

TO THIS:
(more readable and manageable, just make sure the enum is in sync with the gridview)

```
row.Cells[Col.CustomerId.GetVal()].Visible = false;     
row.Cells[Col.OrderNumber.GetVal()].Visible = false; 
row.Cells[Col.ProductNumber.GetVal()].Visible = false;  
. . .
int matchId = row.Cells[Col.CustomerName.GetVal()].Text;
. . .


public enum Col
{
    MatchId = 1,
. . .
    ServiceCode = 9,
    CustomerId = 10,
    CustomerName = 11,
. . .

}

public static class ColExt
{
    static public int GetVal(this Col col)
    {
        return (int)col;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the code is more readable with the enums. But it's important that you have a code generator for the enum(s). Otherwise you do a lot of misstakes, if you have many columns to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Its good Idea if large amount of column is used in a grid or at many pages if same grid is being used. id will be easy to change column value from enum and it will reflect to all the grids....